# Customizing keyboard shortcuts in IPython 5

Tags: ipython, keyboard-shortcuts, prompt-toolkit

In IPython 5.0, with the new prompt_toolkit backend, how can modify or add new keyboard shortcuts? For example, I want to make it so that up arrow goes back in history, rather than doing a history search (which is the default behavior).